# Gmail, First email in thread with labels logging into google sheet

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Thank you in advance for your help.

I am new to google scripting & if someone can help me with a script. 
It will help me in a task as well as in the learning process.

I have a task to record all the emails in google sheets with a specific label, let's say "XYZ"

In the google sheet, I need

1. Sender of the first email of the thread
2. Date of the first email of the thread
3. All the labels on First email of the thread
4. Subject of first email of the thread

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

This should get you started.  It's not complete but if you keep you code formatted properly, the way content assist likes it and you keeping fixing syntax errors then code assist in the script editor will help you work your way through most of the code.  Use the documentation and pay attention to what kind of object is returned from various functions.

```
function getEmails() {
  var threads=GmailApp.getInboxThreads();
  for(var i=0;i<threads.length;i++) {
    var thread=threads[i];
    var firstmessage=thread.getMessages()[0];
    var firstmessagesender=firstmessage.getFrom();
    var firstMessageSubject=thread.getFirstMessageSubject();
    var firstMessageLabels=thread.getLabels();

  }
}
```