# Recent email of the thread - Gmail

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Can anyone help me with a query that I can use to extract data from my Gmail?

Here are the requirements,

- Date range, so I can select a specific date
- Subject of the email
- Date of the email
- Body of recent email of the thread
- Sender of the recent email of the thread
- Receiver of the recent email of the thread

```
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

function onOpen(e) {
    ui.createMenu("Gmail Manager").addItem("Get Emails", "getEmails").addToUi();
}

function getEmails() {
    const threads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads();
    for (let i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
        const msgs = threads[i].getMessages();
        const lastmsg = msgs[msgs.length - 1];
        var firstmessage = thread.getMessages()[0];
        var recentmessagesender = firstmessage.getFrom();
        var recentMessageSubject = thread.getFirstMessageSubject();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please be more specific about what are you trying to achieve? What exactly is not working from the code you have shared? @TaimoorGill

Comment: @ale13 actually the whole code is not working. I am not sure why. Can you please help me with this?

Comment: Are you getting any errors? What exactly does "the whole code is not working" mean?

Comment: No the sheet is blank. It says script running, but there are no results.

Comment: You are not writing anything to the sheet nor to the logger - can you provide more details about your task?

Comment: Does this help:https://stackoverflow.com/a/67205882/7215091

Comment: @ale13 the task is to get the recent email of the thread. If there is only 01 email, that should also be included. All other details are also required like in mentioned above.

Comment: @MetaMan thank you but i think, that is something different that you provided.

Comment: I have posted an answer below. Kindly check it and let me know if it works for you! @TaimoorGill

Comment: @ale13 can you tell me how can i get the results on a spreasheet :)

Comment: Please check the answer, I have specified it there. Cheers!

Comment: @TaimoorGill you should provide feedback when someone answers your question, specially since they spent their time in helping you. I see it's [not the first time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59872348/gmail-first-email-in-thread-with-labels-logging-into-google-sheet) you do this . That answer was useful since you used here the exact same code someone else wrote for you. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers. Accepting the answer is the best, but a thank you would be enough too.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve the recent message of *each* thread, you can try this:

#### Code

```
function getEmails() {
  let threads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads();
  for (let i=0; i< threads.length; i++) {
    let thread = threads[0];
    let messages = thread.getMessages();
    let recentMessage = messages[0];
    let recentMessageSender = recentMessage.getFrom();
    let recentMessageReceiver = recentMessage.getTo();
    let recentMessageSubject = recentMessage.getSubject();
    let recentMessageDate = recentMessage.getDate();
    let recentMessageBody = recentMessage.getPlainBody();

  }
}
```

#### Explanation

The above snippet gathers all the threads and then for each thread it retrieves the first message, this being denoted by the `messages[0]`. Afterwards, the **sender**, **received**, **subject**, **date** and **body** are retrieved using the specific methods for the `GmailMessage` object.

However, depending on what exactly you plan on doing with the information obtained, you can either use :

- `console.log` in order to display it to the logger

**OR** if you want to write it to the spreadsheet, you will have to

- use the `SpreadsheetApp` service, something similar to this:

```
// add this outside the `for` loop
let activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
```

```
// add this inside the `for` loop
activeSheet.getRange(i+1,1).setValue(recentMessageSender);
activeSheet.getRange(i+1,2).setValue(recentMessageReceiver);
```

When writing to the spreadsheet, you will have to take into account the range you want to paste the date onto. In the above example, the first row will correspond to the first message of the first thread, the second row will correspond to the first message of the second thread and so on.

#### Reference

- [Apps Script GmailMessage Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message);
- [Apps Script Sheet Class - getRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column);
- [Apps Script Range Class - setValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue).